# How to load nested data from html table

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

I'm coming to you because I use the library Tabulator in my Laravel project and I have some difficulties to manipulate nested data. To load an HTML Tabulator Table , I have to do it via an HTML Table and via an array of object on JS side. On the JS side, I know how to do it but I'm having trouble loading via the HTML table. In the [documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/data#table), it says :

> You can define the columns in the usual way with the columns option, or you can set them as th elements in the thead of a table.

> Any rows of data in the tbody of the table will automatically be converted to tabulator data in displayed in the resulting table.

> You can set options parameters directly in the HTML by using tabulator- attributes on the table and th elements, these will then be set as configuration options on the table.

Unfortunately for attributes passed via HTML elements it seems to be quite limited. Because on JS side we have to use an object as below to add data (including nested data) :

```json
[
    {id:1, name:"Billy Bob", age:"12", "_children":[
        {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1"}, //child rows nested under billy bob
        {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42"},
        {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", "_children":[
            {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16"}, //child rows nested under brendon philps
            {id:6, name:"Frank Peoney", age:"12"},
        ]},
    ]},
    {id:7, name:"Jenny Jane", age:"1"},
    {id:8, name:"Martha Tiddly", age:"42", "_children":[
        {id:9, name:"Frasier Franks", age:"125"}, //child row nested under martha tiddly
    ]},
    {id:10, name:"Bobby Green", age:"11"},
]
```

But on HTMl Tabulator Table side, I have absolutely no idea. Nothing is mentioned in the documentation. However i tried something like that without success :

```html
<table id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th tabulator-field="data0">Data 0</th>
            <th tabulator-field="data1">Data 1</th>
            <th tabulator-field="data2">Data 2</th>
            <th tabulator-field="_children"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($orderlines as $orderline)
        <!-- @foreach -> syntaxe blade blade syntax that is unique to Laravel -->
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $object->getData0() }}</td>
            <td>{{ $object->getData1() }}</td>
            <td>{{ $object->getData2() }}</td>
            <td>[
                {data0:1, data1:"Billy Bob", data2:"12", "_children":[
                {data0:2, data1:"Mary May", data2:"1"}, //child rows nested under billy bob
                {data0:3, data1:"Christine Lobowski", data2:"42"},
                {data0:4, data1:"Brendon Philips", data2:"125", "_children":[
                {data0:5, data1:"Margret Marmajuke", data2:"16"}, //child rows nested under brendon philps
                {data0:6, data1:"Frank Peoney", data2:"12"},
                ]},
                ]},
                ]</td> <!-- example of json object -->
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    new Tabulator("#mytable", {
        dataTree:true
    });
</script>
```

If someone would have an idea I would be interested :)

Comment: Can you please share what output you need ?

Comment: @HirenPatel something like that http://tabulator.info/examples/4.9#tree

Comment: I think your implementation is wrong.

Comment: @HirenPatel what did you mean ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! :) Is it possible for you to output the data directly as JSON? Is there some specific reason why you built the table in HTML directly?

Comment: Exactly, Provide data to tabulator in JSON directly.

Comment: @JoelPeltonen Yes it is possible to output the data directly in JSON. And the reason I pass the data to an HTML table is because I want to avoid losing the data, so I store the data from the html table on the server side and if a page reload is done then the data is sent back to the Blade view containing the HTML table (which will implement the data on the HTML table). If you don't understand i can show you some code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would suggest at this point, if I understand your situation correctly, is to try and output the data as JSON and just let Tabulator handle the entire HTML table generation.

I'm not 100% sure if this approach would work for you, but in pseudocode something like this

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
    const data = `{{ $orderlines }}`
    const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        data: data,
        dataTree:true,
        dataTreeStartExpanded:true,
        columns:[
            {title:"Name",     field:"name",     width:200},
            {title:"Location", field:"location", width:150},
            // Descriptions of your data columns here
        ],
    });
    console.log(table);
</script>
```

Comment: @peter I agree with you, I read the documentation several times and I found this: 

> Note: This approach can only be used for text, numeric and boolean options, for callbacks and functions you will have to use the constructor object described below.

Therefore what you propose seems to be the only solution to my problem.